# AndEngine NullpointerException when creating sound

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, andengine, audio

Quick question:
I've got this code:

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    instance = this;

    mCamera = new org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
    //engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);


    return engineOptions;

}
```

And

```
protected void onCreateResources() {





    SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/");



    try {
        this.testSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "explosion.ogg");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}
```

And I finaly play it on another class that has this activity as a field :

```
    activity.mCurrentScene.registerTouchArea(image);
    activity.mCurrentScene.setOnAreaTouchListener(new IOnAreaTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            Zancudo.this.activity.testSound.play();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any ideas why am I getting a nullpointer exception ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For play sound you are using like below

```
Zancudo.this.activity.testSound.play();
```

This looks like the issue because here the activity object is not instantiated in the `Zancudo` class.

To access the testSound you need to get the instance of the **Zancudo** activity.